# How to set the location of a program's sound in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, audio, surround-sound, digital-audio

I want to hear Firefox in my surround sound headset from the front left and front right, music from behind left and behind right, and the Unity engine from left and right. How can I set a specific program's audio location?